# AWS: specify Lambda version for Cognito trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a Cognito User Pool and corresponding a Identity pool.

I want to call a specific version of my Lambda function on `Post authentication` or some other trigger like that.

I don't see an option to specify a version code in the Console although the examples all have a version number.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html

```
{
    "version": number,
    "triggerSource": "string",
    "region": AWSRegion,
    "userPoolId": "string",
    ...
}
```

How do I specify the version of the lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognito, always uses the latest version or whatever is the default version provided by lambda.

The version that you are referring in the documentation is the event version number. In case in the future Cognito introduces a breaking change to the format of the request you can protect your code from breaking by checking this version number.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible updating user pool trigger configuration with AWS CLI using Lambda arn that includes alias, like

```
aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id _awsregion_id_ --lambda-config PostAuthentication=arn:aws:lambda:_awsregion_:_awsid_:function:_functionname_:_alias_
```

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. While the AWS CLI allows you provide an ARN that includes the alias, it doesn't actually work -- for example, if you set the `VerifyAuthChallengeResponse` to use a Lambda ARN that includes an alias, all auth challenges will fail.

Comment: Following up my comment: per https://stackoverflow.com/a/53751277/749272 you CAN use the alias ARN, but you MUST ALSO manually grant Cognito permission to invoke that specific ARN. Whatever Cognito usually does to manually grant itself permission via the AWS console does not happen automatically when you use the AWS CLI. @alessio it you edit your answer, I will upvote.