# adding aliased lambda function in cognito pool trigger drop down selection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have created a lambda function, published a version of it and pointed that version to an alias.
ARN for my lambda function:
**"ARN - arn:aws:lambda:aws_region:aws_id:function:function_name:production"**.
So in cognito pool triggers, I need to assign this lambda function into "Custom message" section, but it's a drop down which populates lambda function without any aliased name. 
Problem is, how to assign the aliased version of the lambda function from drop down into the cognito pool triggers.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @alexis-n-o answer, you will very likely need to grant cognito permission to invoke the aliased lambda function.  The console does this for you automatically.

**Create or update pool**

```
create-user-pool
    --pool-name my-pool
    --lambda-config CustomMessage=arn:aws:lambda:aws_region:aws_id:function:function_name:production


update-user-pool
    --user-pool-id <pool-id>
    --lambda-config CustomMessage=arn:aws:lambda:aws_region:aws_id:function:function_name:production
```

**Assign cognito permission to invoke the lambda:**

```
aws lambda add-permission 
--function-name arn:aws:lambda:<lambda-region>:<account>:function:<lambda-name>:<alias-name> 
--source-arn <user-pool-arn> 
--action lambda:* 
--statement-id <your-statement-id-here> 
--principal cognito-idp.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: `--action lambda:InvokeFunction` should be enough. That's what the Cognito console automatically sets.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the AWS cli to create the pool and set the ARN of the aliased Lambda.

```
create-user-pool
    --pool-name my-pool
    --lambda-config CustomMessage=arn:aws:lambda:aws_region:aws_id:function:function_name:production
```

If the pool is already created:

```
update-user-pool
    --user-pool-id <pool-id>
    --lambda-config CustomMessage=arn:aws:lambda:aws_region:aws_id:function:function_name:production
```