# Cognito trigger error: Invalid version. Version should be 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am deploying (using AWS CDK) a Congito event trigger for custom messages. However when invoked it always returns the error: `Invalid version. Version should be 1`

Searching did not provide an answer:

- [AWS: specify Lambda version for Cognito trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477594/aws-specify-lambda-version-for-cognito-trigger)
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=772639

What I have done after initial error:

- attempted to create a version "1" alias
- copied verbatim the sample lambda code from AWS docs

The answer on above SO question seems to indicate it should just use latest version.

Any idea what this error means?  I don't see anything in the Cognito user pool CDK to add a version number besides me creating an alias and force that version as I did.

Answer (score 3):

Ah.... I was only returning the emailTemplate and emailSubject. I needed to return the entire original event.

```
event.response.emailMessage = emailMessage
event.response.emailSubject = emailSubject
return event
```